# Where are the Android manifest file data saved in Android?

Tags: android, permissions

I am working on an Android project where I want to change the permissions of an application at runtime.
To achieve that, I thought of changing the `android:permission` tag in the Android Manifest file.
But to change this at run time, I guess it might be possible to change the database where Android manifest file's data are stored. 
Please let me know where this database is stored and is it feasible to change it at runtime.

Comment: Android Manifest file cannot be edited at run time. That would be a huge security flaw.

Comment: tell me, would you like to instal an app with no permissions and then this app changes its own  ?permissions and does bad, nasty things with your device

Comment: You should use *SharedPreferences* to change something at run time

Comment: If i have the android source code.. i can give permission to my app which can access the database where the manifest's data is stored.. 
and change it at runtime.. build the code and flash this.. i dont find any problem with this..

Comment: Sure, it's not a problem for *you*.  But I don't want applications changing their manifest while running on my hardware.

Answer (score 1):

The Manifest.xml file is stored in the signed apk which is in the systems area that you don't have access to without root.  So it would only work on rooted devices, you would need to obtain root, possible decrypt the apk, unzip it, make the modification and then, somehow, resign it with the original keystore that was initially used.  If you are trying to modify one of your own apps I guess it's possible but it seems like a lot of trouble to go to.

Comment: +1 :any clue on "it's possible but it seems like a lot of trouble to go to."

Comment: Even then, you could only change the permissions of the application the next time it runs, not the permissions of the running instance.